# Add Documentation to custom BindingAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, javadoc, android-databinding

I have written a custom binding like this one:

```
object Binding {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("showIf")
    fun showIf(view: View, condition: Boolean){
        if (condition) {
            view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            view.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

This works nice, and is even listed in the auto-complete suggestions, when editing the layout.
But... how can I add javadoc to this method, so people can see what it does in the autocomplete popup shown below:

[image]

I tried adding regular documentation (javadoc style)

```
/**
 * @param view
 * @param condition View.VISIBLE if true, View.GONE otherwise
 */ 
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("showIf")
fun showIf(view: View, condition: Boolean){ ... }
```

but Android Studio (or the editor?) does not seem to pick it up.
Any suggestions are welcome.